# How to std::sort a vector using a property of a separate class

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a Node class with an integer property Time and a `std::vector<Node*> queue` where a lot of Nodes are in. I want to use the `std::sort` function to order the queue by time but I'm not sure how to do that. I know the beginning is `std::sort(queue.begin(), queue.end())` but I dont know what to put for the third parameter

Comment: What do you mean by "order the queue by time" and how does time relate to `Node`?

Comment: Like if the queue had 6 nodes in them with the times (1,5,88,43,25,98) I want the queue to rearrange and end up as (1,5,25,43,88,98). And the class of Node has a integer field called time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to suply custom comparator.

```
// comparator object
struct comparator {
    bool operator()(const Node* node1, const Node* node2) const {
        return node1->getTime() < node2->getTime();
    }
};

std::vector<Node*> nodes;
//...
std::sort(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), comparator());

// or if you can, use C++11's lambdas
std::sort(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), [](const Node* node1, const Node* node2) {
    return node1->getTime() < node2->getTime();
}
```

This should work :) [Live demo here](http://ideone.com/cfhwDm)

---

Be advised, look into [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) before asking questions. There is an example with custom comparator there.

Comment: So I tried this. And got a bunch of errors on the second "const" in the expression. Any reason for this?

Comment: It's supposed to be `operator()` instead of `operator<`. Sorry :)

Comment: @user2678799: [Live demo](http://ideone.com/cfhwDm)

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler supports C++ 14 then you can write simply

```
std::sort( queue.begin(), queue.end(), 
           []( auto n1, auto n2 ) { return n1->Time < n2->Time; } );
```

or

```
std::sort( queue.begin(), queue.end(), 
           []( const auto &n1, const auto &n2 ) { return n1->Time < n2->Time; } );
```

Otherwise you should write

```
std::sort( queue.begin(), queue.end(), 
           []( Node *n1, Node *n2 ) { return n1->Time < n2->Time; } );
```

or

```
std::sort( queue.begin(), queue.end(), 
           []( const Node * &n1, const Node * &n2 ) { return n1->Time < n2->Time; } );
```

If your compiler does not support the current C++ Standard then you can define simply a function

```
bool TimeComare(const Node *n1, const Node *n2 )
{
    return n1->Time < n2->Time;
}
```

and call the algorithm like

```
std::sort( queue.begin(), queue.end(), TimeCompare );
```

Comment: Tried this and forgot to mention that my teacher requires that we use C++ 98 so I got a ton of errors!

Comment: If you deal with pointers, i guess it's better to copy by value then reference (performance). If you deal with "anything" ,then reference is the best way.

@user2678799: - try my answer, it uses C++98 feature (callable objects).

Comment: so use a function instead of a lambda

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thank you! Totally worked now haha

Comment: *my teacher requires that we use C++ 98* fire your teacher.